# Run two scripts from package.json in Netifly

Tags: reactjs, github, package.json, json-server, concurrently

I have deployed my React app successfully in Netifly.
[My app live URL](https://inspiring-poitras-f22437.netlify.app/)

Here is my `package.json` file's `scripts`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "json-server": "json-server --watch db.json --port 3003",
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"npm start\" \"npm run json-server\"",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

But the problem is: the site unable to show any kind of data. Please visit to have an idea. Because, `json-server` as backend serves `db.json`. It's not running in production.

Locally i can run `yarn start:dev` but couldn't able to run both scripts concurrently. What will be the proper `scripts` to run both `react-scripts start` && `json-server --watch db.json --port 3003` in production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found myself the solution: `"start": "concurrently \"react-scripts start\" \"npm run json-server\"",` by updating solves the problem.